# WPF Memory Leak from Drag-Drop

Tags: wpf

Using Red-Gate tools we have detected that the System.Windows.DataObject is holding a reference to a dragObject (a framework element) that is hanging around from an operation long since completed.

How does one "clear" the drag object once DragDrop.DoDragDrop? Is there a way to pass a null through this and have it fall right through?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just discovered this gem myself, my solution was to use a WeakReference to the data item being dragged.

```cs
DataObject data = new DataObject(new WeakReference(this.draggedData));
DragDrop.DoDragDrop((DependencyObject)sender, data, DragDropEffects.Move);
```

and then in the drop

```cs
var draggedItem = e.Data.GetData(this.format.Name) as WeakReference;
if (draggedItem != null && draggedItem.IsAlive)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Wow: this is a truely great solution. A short explanation as to why this works: DoDragDrop() will only finish executing after the drag-drop operation has finished. Therefore, the function that executes DoDragDrop() always holds the last strong reference to the data object and will only release it after the drag-drop operation has finished.

Answer (score 1):

First of all [a big thanks to Ian Oakes for his solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13966606/74612). I needed a slight variant however: I had to make sure that dropping always works, even if the garbage collector ran in the meanwhile. Here is the solution:

```
public partial class DragDropDemo : Window
{
    private SomeDragDropData _dragDropData;

    private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            _dragDropData = new SomeDragDropData { Text = "Some drag data" };
            var dataObject = new DataObject("SomeObjectTypeId", new WeakReference<SomeDragDropData>(_dragDropData));
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop((DependencyObject)sender, dataObject, DragDropEffects.Move);
            _dragDropData = null;
        }
    }

    private void OnDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var weakReferenceData = e.Data.GetData("SomeObjectTypeId") as WeakReference<SomeDragDropData>;
        if (weakReferenceData != null && weakReferenceData.IsAlive)
            MessageBox.Show(weakReferenceData.Target.Text);
    }
}

public class SomeDragDropData
{
    public string Text;
}
```

Some remarks:

- The reason this works is because DoDragDrop blocks until the user triggered the drop operation. Hence, _dragDropData is made null only after the drag-drop operation is fully finished.
- It is very important to make _dragDropData a member variable. Merely making it a local variable is not enough: when the garbage collector is triggered the object *might* get disposed. This results in a very hard to reproduce bug because it is not because the garbage collector is triggered that the object necessarily gets cleaned up. From what I saw it only gets cleaned up when a lot of memory got allocated and deallocated

Comment: You don't need a member variable, make `SomeDragDropData` local then replace `_dragDropData = null;` with `GC.KeepAlive(_dragDropData)`. The [`GC.KeepAlive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive.aspx) method is designed to do this exact job (keeping a reference around a extra length of time so it does not get disposed but without doing anything with the data)