# Windows Forms DataObject leaks memory

Tags: .net, winforms, memory-leaks

In my profiler I can see that whenever a drag & drop operation is issued, the DataObject and all the data that it contains do leak.

I know I could use the solution provided under [WPF Memory Leak from Drag-Drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645946/wpf-memory-leak-from-drag-drop), but I want to avoid this.

Is there any other way to prevent the memory leak at all? DataObject unfortunately doesn't have a Dispose()-method.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the solution you linked to? Also it's not really a "memory leak" it a reference being held much longer than you want it to.

Comment: The problem is, that the DataObject-instances themselves are never released - therefore, this is a leak. I could use the WeakReference-solution, but before I do this I wanted to see if anybody has a solution for the root of the problem.